# VBA - run time error 9 and using * for a variable worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm having some frustrations whilst working with a workbook that has a variable name, having read many previous questions about using * i'm still facing a run time 9 error no matter what I try. Therefore requesting some help on this subject.

The workbook that contains the code needs to copy data from workbook "Today Data 19-Nov-2018" which is referenced in cell B3 in the below code. The date changes each day but other things are also variable eg 19/Nov/18, 19th-Nov-2018.

For the below code, if I match cell B3 to the exact name of the workbook, the code works so it can't be that sheet1 doesn't exist. However I've tried all of the below variations to the value of cell B3 in order to accommodate the variable naming convention and all result in run time error

Today Data * , Today Data* , Today Data * .xlsx

```
Dim WorkbookName As Variant

WorkbookName = Range("B3").Value

Workbooks(WorkbookName).Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
Workbooks("Stock Cash").Worksheets("STOCK Detail").Range("A1").PasteSpecial 
xlPasteValues
```

*"Stock Cash" is the current workbook that contains this code

Comment: Is the workbook in question already open?

Comment: Yes it is already open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the workbook is **already open** and you are just having issues setting a reference to it, then a `For Each` statement should do the job.

Loop through all open workbooks in the `Application.Workbooks` collection, and by using the `Like` operator, you can find partial matches and set the workbook you need to a new var `myWB`.

It's probably a good idea to use separate wb variables (which has already been done using `wb` and `myWB` in the below example) only because you don't want to use the last wb in the loop if no match was found (meaning you will get a RT #91 error - which is better than accidentally moving data from the incorrect wb).

```
Dim wb As Workbook, myWB As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "*" & Range("B3").Value & "*" Then
        Set myWB = wb
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb

myWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
```

#### Side Note:

I would *strongly recommend* that you also qualify the `Range("B3").Value` with both your workbook (can be [`ThisWorkbook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook) but **not** [`ActiveWorkbook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activeworkbook)) and the worksheet - especially since you are dealing with multiple open workbooks.

So, something like:

```
If wb.Name Like "*" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("..SheetName..").Range("B3").Value & "*" Then
    ...
```

Comment: I gave this a go, and something must be off with how I'm doing it. The value in range B3 is "Daily Data 19-November-2018" whereas the workbook is actually called "Daily Data 19-November-2018 (4)". Almost the exact same. But when I step through I can see that the loop isn't finding it since it's setting mywb = Nothing

Comment: @A.J.A Oh I took it you were using wildcards in B3, like `Today Data *`

Comment: Yeah even when I amend the value in Range B3 to be exactly the same as the workbook, it's still not picking it up.

Comment: Okay, I updated code - don't use wildcards in the cell anymore - it's hardcoded in now

Comment: Haha, so I put the wildcard back and it works. Great. Thanks for the help